# Import a huge XML file data into MySQL database using CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, xml, cakephp, stream

I developed an XML import using CakePHP but is just for small XML file.

```
App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');

...

/* into method */

$xml = Xml::build($xmlFile);
$xmlArray = Xml::toArray($xml);
if (!empty($xmlArray)) {
    $this->$tableCode->saveMany($xmlArray, array('deep' => true)
}
```

I need to develop a system for huge files but I didn't found library and documentation for CakePHP  2.x.

An idea? I saw that exist the library xml-string-streamer. Is this possible import it into CakePHP 2.x?

Thanks.

Comment: How large of files are we talking about? I think the limitation is not the script its self but the server configuration.

Comment: Usually you would handle larger (and longer) save operations to the CLI - and execute them from there. in CLI there is no timeout issue. Only memory limit, but you could leverage newer PHP features maybe to avoid that, too.

Comment: Until 500 MB, the server configuration do not support this size. But I don't want change the memory_limit and max_execution_time in php.ini.

Comment: Then read it in chunks that are smaller than 500mb...